# Expand package import path

Tags: go

Is there a Go standard library function to expand package import paths?

For example, I'd like a function `Expand` with the following behavior:

```
Expand("path/filepath")   => "/usr/local/go/src/path/filepath"
Expand("go/types")        => "/usr/local/go/src/go/types"
Expand("my/package/path") => "/Users/kvu/go/src/my/package/path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

[path.Join](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join)([os.Getenv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv)("GOPATH"), "/my/package/path")